# Firebase storage not displaying image

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

Before writing question I would say that I'm new in iOS development and in firebase too :) That's why I apologize in advance for a silly question :)

When I load profile.png image from firebase storage programmatically it's loaded correctly without any problems.

```
static func getUserImage(_ uid: String, completion: @escaping (UIImage?, NSError?) -> Void) {
        // Create a reference to the file you want to download.
        let storage = FIRStorage.storage()
        let userUID: String = String(describing: uid)
        let storageRef = storage.reference(forURL: "...some address...")
        let downloadRef = storageRef.child("\(userUID)/profilePhoto.png")

        // Download in memory with a maximum allowed size of 10MB (10 * 1024 * 1024 bytes).
        downloadRef.data(withMaxSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024) {
            data, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                NSLog("Retrieve image failed:\n\(error?.localizedDescription)")
                completion(nil, error as! NSError)
                return
            }
            guard let image = UIImage(data: data) else {
                NSLog("Image decoding failed:\n\(data)")
                completion(nil, nil)
                return
            }
            assert(error == nil)
            completion(image, nil)
        }
    }
```

But when I go to firebase storage in browser and try to search it by **uid** manually from list I can't find it - it doesn't exist. Could you explain me how it's possible? It problem exists only for several images in firebase storage.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The storage console should contain a "folder" with the UID of the user, otherwise I'm not really sure where the image would be loaded from. Did you refresh the console? If so, can you share a small screenshot of what you see?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes, you are true. I should see "folder" with the UID name. But it doesn't exist. But when I try to build url to this folder manually and  enter there by force (something like this: {"some_url}/files%252FgoIRn08skBPuIFRhsN6cQv0erxx1%252F") I get next screen - https://www.screencast.com/t/uOSvxAxdaSI

Answer (score 0):

Folder name should start with capital letter.